# Eclipse programming error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, splash-screen

Can anybody tell me what causes this error?

**LogCat**

```
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1970
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj/com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1635)
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
01-22 13:48:09.379: E/AndroidRuntime(28005):    at com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.SplashActivity$IntentLauncher.run(SplashActivity.java:45
```

**Here the manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me

Comment: Add your activity `MainActivity` in `manifest.xml`. If its there verify the package name.

Comment: check your package name com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj/com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.MainActivity and add that activity in your manifest.xml

Comment: you have not declared activity in your manifest file

Comment: I'm trying to add a splash screen,not the MainActivity

Comment: post your `AndroidMainfest.xml` code

Comment: <activity android:name="com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity>

Comment: dear @HaxhiBekaj where are your SplashActivity ?

Comment: In my package.Its a .java file.Here http://jpst.it/EZCc

Comment: @HaxhiBekaj I have edited my answer

Comment: see my updated answer bellow. You need to add both activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You probably are missing the declaration of your `MainActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` as suggested by your error message, your manifest should look like this :

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your

> SplashActivity.java & MainActivity.java

to

> AndroidManifest.xml

like this:

```
 <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name="com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.MainActivity" />
        </application>
```

Comment: <activity
                android:name="com.haxhibekaj.skenderaj.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:screenOrientation="portrait">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

Comment: where is SplashActivity  ?

Comment: in AndroidManifest it is also required. Post your complete AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: see my updated answer. your all activity must be declare in AndroidManifest.xml. Calling Activity SplashActivity which is always open when APP  launches so It need  <intent-filter> other Activity only need to register in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 0):

> have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Make sure you declare your class in **Mainfest.xml**

Example

```
<activity android:name="Your_class_name"></activity>
```

If you have added, but the error still exists, most probably is because you declare wrongly or package declared wrongly.

This is the way how to declare class name with package

```
<activity android:name=".PACKAGE_NAME.Your_class_name"></activity>
```

**Edited**

In your case, you should declare your packeage name and class name in this way

```
<activity android:name=".skenderaj.SplashActivity"></activity>
```